# Use flask-mail with Amazon SES

Tags: flask, amazon-ses, flask-mail

I want to use Flask mail with Amazon SES. I know it's possible to use the boto library instead, but in the long term, I want to use different smtps. (this is thus a different question than [How to adapt flask-mail to support two SMTP accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406729/how-to-adapt-flask-mail-to-support-two-smtp-accounts))

So, I registered in Amazon SES, and got a client id and secret id. I have also registered the mail adress with which I want to send emails in my application. Now, my question is, how should I configure my application (see below variables)?

```
MAIL_USERNAME = config.get('mail_service', 'USER')
MAIL_PASSWORD = config.get('mail_service', 'PASSWD')
MAIL_SERVER = config.get('mail_service', 'MAIL_SERVER')
MAIL_PORT = 587
```

For MAIL_SERVER, I already found it. However, for username and password, I'm not sure how to provide both mail_adress (example@gmail.com), client_id (SES) And both password (mail password + secret_id from SES).

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot